My Centos machines revert time after reboot
I have 3 machines on VMware ESXi v6.5. I set time manually:
timedatectl set-time '16:00:00'` and check time with `timedatectl

[root@abcd ~]# timedatectl
  Local time: Sun 2024-04-07 16:00:30 +430
  Universal time: Sun 2024-04-07 12:30:30 UTC
  RTC time: Sun 2024-04-07 15:02:38
  Time zone: Asia/Tehran (+0430, +0330)
  NTP enabled: no
  NTP synchronized: no
  RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: yes
    .
    .
    . 

I try these steps:

I copy system time to hardware clock:
 hwclock  --systohc


Edit /etc/adjtime file to:
 0.0 0 0.0
 0
 LOCAL
 EOF



But after rebooting, the machine that revert to 17:05:00. But I want 16:05:00 in ('+330').
How can I prevent auto update time?
Note: my machines are not connected to the internet (they are offline) and I don't have any NTP server
